# SUM dentro de SUM Entity Framework perfomance

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

Fiz uma query com entity framework e estou tendo problemas com desempenho.

```
 public static Decimal ValorPrevisto(this ClinicaModel clinica)
        {
            return clinica.Contratos.Sum(c => c.Mensalidades.Where(m => m.Pagamento != null).Sum(t => t.Valor)) / 2;
        }
```

Este código está demorando mais de 3 minutos para ser executado, pois ele está varrendo registro por registro, pesquisei varias vezes e não encontrei uma forma de melhorar o desempenho.

Classe ClinicaModel

```
public class ClinicaModel : Base.BaseModel
    {
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public DateTime HoraExpedienteInicio { get; set; }
        public DateTime HoraExpedienteTermino { get; set; }
        public int DuracaoConsulta { get; set; }
        public int DiasExpediente { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public virtual EnderecoModel Endereco { get; set; }
        public virtual ContatoModel Telefone { get; set; }
        public virtual PessoaFisicaModel Responsavel { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<UsuarioModel> Usuarios { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<DoutorModel> Doutores { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ConvenioModel> Convenios { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ContratoModel> Contratos { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PagamentoModel> Pagamentos { get; set; }
        public ClinicaModel()
        {
            Usuarios = new HashSet<UsuarioModel>();
            Doutores = new HashSet<DoutorModel>();
            Convenios = new HashSet<ConvenioModel>();
            Pagamentos = new HashSet<PagamentoModel>();
            Contratos = new HashSet<ContratoModel>();

        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Nome;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Este código com certeza não demora nem 1 milissegundo, afinal ele só monta a expressão e não faz consulta alguma. O LINQ não funciona como as pessoas imaginam. Pode estar demorando em outro lugar. De qualquer forma só com este código não dá para afirmar onde pode estar o problema. Pode ser até mesmo no banco de dados. Não existe milagre, uma soma de uma quantidade grande de linhas onde não pode ser usado índice e se o banco de dados não tiver formas de otimização, ficará lento mesmo. Este código não indica nada que possa ser otimizado aí.

Comment: acontece q eu executo essa consulta no banco de dados em sql e não demora, só ai mesmo, pq na consulta parece q ele varre registro por registro ao invés de fazer um calculo só.

Comment: clinica.Contrato que classe é essa? poderia mostrar a classe ClinicaModel?

Comment: Pronto Editado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se nao me engano, navigation properties, fora do context IQueryable sao carregadas na memoria usando lazy load.

No seu caso, por ser sum the sum, retornaria varias consultas ao banco, pois provavelmente vc nao esta usando IQueryable.

Sei que voce criou essa propriedade no intuito de com uma unica consulta retornar o valor, mas creio que nao seja possivel pois voce está fora do Context.
Ja se voce usar diretamente do context, isso se ornar possivel, pois voce ira trabalahr com iqueryable do DbSet de clincas.
Teste o seguinte fora do escopo da propriedade e veja se a performance aumenta, assim voce vai entender o problema:

```
 var context = new MyContext();// nao sei qual o nome do seu context de entitdades
 var clinicaId = 1;// ponha o Id de teste aqui

 var valorPrevistoClinca = context.ClinicaModel.Where(c=> c.Id = clinicaId).SelectMany(c=> c.Mensalidades.Where(m=> m.Pagamento != null)).Sum(m=> m.Valor) / 2;
```

Rodou rapido?

Comment: o problema é que estou usando camadas, e o contexto fica fora da camada das views..., mas acho que entendi o problema, pois quando eu debugo ele realiza varias queries percorrendo registro por registro!

Comment: sim, imaginei isso, por isso que nesse caso,acho melhor voce criar outra classe para que a view consuma, onde voce possa consultar o valor prevista, fornencendo como argumento a clinica ou o id dela.